# artefact lines in exported pdf for stacked barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am plotting a stacked barplot with matplotlib bar plot and some of the bars can be empty.
The plot looks perfect in the jupyter and when I export it as png but in pdf and svg I see thin lines for empty bars.

[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM3Vu.png)

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0niMe.png)

the code for plotting is the following:

```
barlist = ax.bar(elements, values, bottom=bottom, label=i, width=0.8, linewidth = 0)

for index, bar in enumerate(barlist):

     bar.set_color(colors[index])
```

Is it possible to somehow remove these lines?